# JavaScript: The Good Parts White space railroad diagrams confusing

Tags: javascript, whitespace

I have started reading "Javascript: The Good Parts" and I'm having trouble figuring out what the first path in the White space railroad diagram is for.

Kindly clarify me.

[image: The railroad diagram from the book].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a "railroad diagram", this has some properties in common with a railroad track.

Upon entering the diagram from the left, when arriving at the first switch, there is no option of going left or right. Just like a railroad switch, the diagram switch has two converging tracks, but no way to pass from one of those to the other.

The switch on the right hand side however, with traffic arriving from the left, provides the options of following either of the diverging routes, effectively ending or repeating the syntax rule.

Thus the diagram defines instances of whitespace to be composed of any positive number of spaces, tabs, line ends, or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Railroad diagrams with one bar at each end allow whitespace to be inserted between any pair of tokens. Railroad diagrams with two bars at each end do not. Here the two bars prevent a whitespace diagram from allowing whitespace within a whitespace (a logical absurdity).

The outer loop (the one the question is about), loops back from the output to the input. It allows permissible characters to be consecutively inserted as long as the starting character is in the set {space, tab, line end, /}. Thus "/*qwerty*//*another qwerty*/" is an acceptable whitespace but "/*qwerty*/q" isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
digit ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";**
<constant> ::= <digit> | <digit> <constant>
```

[image]

Think about the above example,a **digital** can be defined as 0 or 1 or 2……
then a **constant** can be defined as one or more **digit**.
comparing to the digram, I think ,this the line you marked represent that something can appear more than one times,that is to say recursively.

Another way to think, it is track can go back to the beginging and restart throug the old track, which means a recursive.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like he's just saying you can use "no characters" as well.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. That line indicates a repetition, not a bypass.